# Custom Payment Module: Executing placeOrder() function in javascript

Tags: magento2, module, payment-methods, place-order

When using a custom payment module, I am trying to execute code with my payment processor then submit the order to the system to run the php methods.  To do that I need to be able to execute the placeOrder() function, in a custom function or override it, from within the method-renderer file.

The button:

```
<button
    data-role="review-save"
    type="submit"
    data-bind="
        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
        click: processPayment,
        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
     "
    class="action primary checkout"
    disabled
>
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
</button>
```

And the function:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form'
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';
        
        return Component.extend({
            //Other function omitted for space
            processPayment() {
                //Some form of placeOrder() function execution
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `placeOrder()` function.

Just put your logic in your Model's `capture` method as per your need

```
public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        if (!$this->canCapture()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The capture action is not available.'));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

reference https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-payment-method/

Comment: It didn't work like that before, but now it does.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: happy to hear. it works for you :) have a nice day ahead